# Excel and cell formatting to text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell with the contents of 41316.  I have it formatted as 20130211.

I need another cell to reference that value, but in the cell have it showing as 20130211 not 41316 formatted.

This maybe an easy one, but for some reason it has me running in circles.

Thanks in advance for all responses.

Answer (score 0):

Excel by default copies the format from a cell formatted as a date to a cell which references it. It sounds in your case that Excel hasn't done that for you, so you just need to format the new cell with your special format : paintbrush tool or Edit..Copy, Edit..Past Special..Formats or Format..Number..Custom and select your format, which will be at the bottom of a long list.

Answer (score 0):

If a string is ok instead of a number, you can decompose that date in parts and concatenate:

Being A1 the cell containing the value:

```
= Year(A1) & "/" & Month(A1) & "/" & Day(A1)
```

The "&" symbol concatenates text. The slashes are optional if you want them separated by slashes.

Answer (score 0):

if your cell referencing 20130211 is 'A1' put `=TEXT(A1,"####")` in your calculation cell.  If you do it this way then it will still read as a number and not a string